# Call to a member function name() on null

Tags: laravel

When I open the `admin/applicant` page,

Here is my routes web.php:

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'],function () {
    $this->resource('applicant', 'ApplicantController')->name('admin.applicant');
});
```

Here is my blade blade.php

```
<a href="{{ route('admin.applicant') }}" class="list-group-item">All Applicant</a>
```

Here is my controller Admin/ApplicantController.php:

```
public function index()
    {
        return view('Admin.applicants.all');
    }
```

I get this error.

[What is this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/X8blb.png)

Answer (score 0):

You need the full class name when using the `resource` helper

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'], function () {
    Route::resource('applicant', ApplicantController::class)
           ->name('admin.applicant');
```

});

Comment: you would need to import the controller namespace `use Admin/ApplicantController; ` or use the full controller namespace `resource('applicant', Admin\ApplicantController::class)`

Comment: I imported Controller

Comment: ah sorry. `resource('applicant', Admin\ApplicantController::class, ['as' => 'admin.applicant'])` try that

Comment: Call to undefined function resource()

Comment: Admin color is red

Comment: Route::resource('applicant', Admin\ApplicantController::class, ['as' => 'admin.applicant']);

Comment: Route [admin.applicant] not defined

Comment: yes so the resource method will create the generic `resource` methods and names https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/controllers#resource-controllers. so use `route('admin.applicant.index')`

Answer (score 0):

You can try:

```
Route::resource('applicant', 'ApplicantController', [
    'names' => [
        'index' => 'admin.applicant.index',
        'store' => 'admin.applicant.new',
        // etc...
    ]
]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Change the code to

```
Route::group(['namespace' => 'Admin', 'prefix' => 'admin'],function () {
  Route::get('applicant', 'ApplicantController@index')->name('admin.applicant');
});
```